# How can we convert a dict into JSON in elm? Or is there any way to stringify the dict as we do in JS?

Tags: json, string, dictionary, decode, elm

```
    = Sku Internals


type alias Internals =
    { id : String --                    READONLY
    , name : String --                  READ/WRITE
    , imgExtras : ( List ImgExtra, String ) --      READ/WRITE
    , availableSizes : List String --   READ/WRITE
  }
```

How to convert the above-declared dictionary value to JSON or string?

Comment: There's no `Dict`s in your code. Do you mean a record type?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by `Dict` you actually mean the `Internals` record, this should encode it as a JSON object, using [elm/json](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest):

```
import Json.Encode as Encode

encodeInternals : Internals -> Encode.Value
encodeInternals internals =
    Encode.object
        [ ( "id", Encode.string internals.string )
        , ( "name", Encode.string internals.name )
        , ( "imgExtras", encodeImgExtras internals.imgExtras )
        , ( "availableSizes", encodeAvailableSizes internals.availableSizes )
        ]

encodeImgExtras : (List ImgExtra, String) -> Encode.Value
encodeImgExtras (imgExtras, string) =
    -- There's no equivalent of a tuple in JSON, so we encode it as an array. But you can of course choose any representation you'd like.
    Encode.list
        [ Encode.list encodeImgExtra imgExtras
        , Encode.string string
        ]

encodeImgExtra : ImgExtra -> Encode.Value
encodeImgExtra imgExtra =
    -- You'll need to implement this one yourself, as you haven't provided its definition.
    ...

encodeAvailableSizes : List String -> Encode.Value
encodeAvailableSizes availableSizes =
    Encode.list Encode.string availableSizes
```